# adding url to BuildConfig file from Gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle, buildconfig

My BuildConfig is generated by Gradle. One of my strings is a URL. When I try to create an apk, I get an error about the `:` in the url. Any ideas what I should tell gradle so this works fine?

Here is what I told Gradle:

```
buildConfigField "String","My_CLOUD_API","http://12.3.456.789:123"
```

Here is the BuildConfig.java constant that was created

```
public static final String My_CLOUD_API = http://12.3.456.789:123;
```

Here is the error:

```
error: ';' expected
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try

```
buildConfigField "String", "MY_CLOUD_API", '"http://12.3.456.789:123"'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try doing:

```
buildConfigField "String", "My_CLOUD_API", "\"http://12.3.456.789:123/\""
```